# Regarding the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Is the following equation true for Tricomi confluent Hypergeometric function? $$\phi(1,0,ax)=1-ax\phi(1,1,ax)$$ here $\phi(.,.,.)$ is the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that using the gamma function could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual examine carefully :)
Using DLMF 13.2.11, 13.6.6
$U(1,0,z)=z\cdot U\left(2,2,z\right)=e^{z}\cdot E_{2}\left(z\right)$
$z\cdot U(1,1,z)=z\cdot e^{z}E_{1}\left(z\right)$
So your question is
$E_{2}\left(z\right)+z\cdot E_{1}\left(z\right)=e^{-z}$
Which matches  8.19.12

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. I checked and my equation exactly matches according to 8.19.12

Comment: Tsk..tsk.. Thanks for giving me a chance to fix mine.